# SQL Server Bulk Insert CSV Issue

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm having an issue that I have not encountered before when bulk inserting from a csv file. For whatever reason, the last column isn't being separated on insert. I kept getting type conversion errors that I knew couldn't be true so I changed the datatype to varchar to see what was being inserted. When I looked at the result set, I saw that instead of (ex. 35.44, 56.82 separated in two columns) in the .csv, I saw (ex. 35.44,56.82 all in one column). This of course is why SQL Server was throwing that error, but how can I resolve this. Am I missing something simple?

To sum it up, the Bulk Insert is ignoring the last field terminator and combining the last two columns into one column

My Bulk Insert:

```
BULK
INSERT [YourTableName]
FROM 'YourFilePathHere' 
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

A row:

```
YSQ3863,Bag 38x63 YELLOW 50/RL,CS,BAG,17.96,LB,1,50,50,YELLOW,,,,,,63,17.96,,,,38,,2394,,8.15,11.58,19.2,222.41
```

Comment: If you are trying this through import wizard in SSMS , please choose appropriate datatype and delimiter in the wizard.

Comment: I'm just using a regular old BULK INSERT statement.

Comment: @gonavy96 Then show us that statement, a sample of the file, and an example of the contents of a malformed row (the complete row).

Comment: that is related to the original file issue, usually happens when column delimiter get confused with the actual symbol, better to use text qualifier to escape it. You need to deal with that from the raw file or using alternative way to load the file such as script task or component.

Comment: @LONG Thank you. I have seen that before (usually with addresses with a comma) and text qualifiers help,  but I don't understand what issue in the CSV could be causing this particular case

Comment: the total number of `,` for that particular line is more than the rest @gonavy96, so the compiler cannot know where to cutoff before it gives you the conversion and truncation issue. The other way is to use another column delimiter such as pipe "|" (assume you do not have actual pipe symbol in the data row)

Comment: This is when you need to quote all of your columns... or change your delimiter in your csv to tab or pipe or something else and save it as txt.

Comment: A CSV is a "Comma separated value" file. Which means your columns are separated by commas. If you put a comma in the data, then you have effectively made another column. As @scsimon noted, the best ways to work around this are a) to export your CSV with quotes around each column (there's an option in Excel and other programs when you save as CSV) or b) use a different type of delimiter so that you can have commas in your data and SQL will separate your columns using a different character. Your issue here is that you probably don't have a proper end of line character.

Comment: @gonavy96  can you post the row as in csv file (pls use an editor and not excel to open the file) and your bulk insert command?

Comment: @LONG this is happening on every row in the result set, and it is just the final two lines. Nothing else seems to have that issue

Comment: YSQ3863,Bag 38x63 YELLOW 50/RL,CS,BAG,17.96,LB,1,50,50,YELLOW,,,,,,63,17.96,,,,38,,2394,,8.15,11.58,19.2,222.41

Comment: My Bulk Statement looks like this:                                                      
    BULK
    INSERT [YourTableName]
    FROM 'YourFilePathHere' 
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )

Comment: @gonavy96, do not understand your description very well. Simple example, for Column A, Column B table, you need to make sure the CSV looks like `TextA,TextB\n`, not `TextA,TextB,TextC\n`, the total number of columns separated by `,` should match the total number of columns, assuming you are populate all the fields

Comment: Sorry @LONG, I didn't mean to say lines, I meant to say its the final two fields separated by one comma on every single row

Comment: It looks how you describe

Comment: the extra `,` could appear anywhere in line and disordering the columns

Comment: Is there a new line among YELLOW and 50/RL ?

Comment: No there is not one

Comment: Can you post a row who is loaded correctly too?

Comment: None of them are loaded correctly. Its the same problem in every single row. Last two columns

Comment: Can you pls post the create table script?  (I'll have to go home now, but tomorrow I'll do some tries with your data)

Comment: I don't know that it would help but I can

Comment: Thank you for offering to help btw